# Setting checked property in Bootstrap btn-group as radio

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap buttons as radio buttons as described [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-examples), under **Radio**. The problem is when trying to add the `checked` property to one of the inputs so that it comes as the default selection when the user first sees the page. I'm trying to do this like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" checked>
```

Unfortunately, the button doesn't come up with the "active" state by default. As can be seen in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gHnT/).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `class="active"`. In twitter bootstrap, you will indicate the default value using the 'active' class

I modified your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gHnT/4/) to use the `active` class

updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gHnT/5/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: But in your example, none of the inputs are "checked" (except visibly). Would just adding checked to the second input do it?

Comment: oh yea... Sorry I must have removed the `checked` accident. Yes adding `checked` to the second input would do it `:)`